# Configuration of Hostfiles on Master node and Slave nodes on Linux system for MPI job run

Tags: linux, compiling, mpi

I am new to MPI. I an using MPICH 3.2 to parallelize my programs. Currently I am trying to run some basic available programs on different physical nodes. I am using the poisson_mpi.f90 to get this going. I am confused after a through search about configuration of Hostfiles on Master node and the Slave nodes. I want to use the ip addres for doin the same. I have prepared a host file as

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.0.23.5       master
10.0.23.6  
10.0.23.11
```

This is the file at /etc/hosts on the master node. Now I need to configure the slave nodes. I have no idea how to do that. for the run command I am using `mpirun --hostfile hostfile.txt -np=20 ./a.out`. I don't know wheather it is right or wrong. My hostfiles.txt is on the same folder form where I am running the program. Its not running the job. Sometimes I get firewell warnnings also. Without the hostfile mpirun executes the command perfectly.

Link to the [POISSON](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/mpi/poisson_mpi.f90) equation solver. This is a MPI version.

Help me configuring and running the mpirun commands.

Thanks in advance.